# Open file dialog and select a file using WPF controls and Ironpython

Tags: python, wpf, xaml, ironpython

I have a GUI created by xaml and linked with my python code. In this GUI, I have a button, when you click on it. I want to open up a file dialog and select a path or file. I created my Click Handler but I do not know how I could open a dialog:

```
self.Sim0Button.Click += self.askopenfile(0)
def askopenfile(self, entryindex):
    self.fileloc =
```

I appreciate if you can help me on that: 
The tkinter equivalent command is:

```
self.fileloc = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
self.sim_name = os.path.basename(self.fileloc)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the default `OpenFileDialog` in the .net framework. Just do the following things.

You need to import it:

```
from Microsoft.Win32 import OpenFileDialog
```

Than use it in your click event:

```
dialog = OpenFileDialog()
dialog.Filter = "All Files|*.*"
if dialog.ShowDialog():
    selectedFile = dialog.FileName
```

The variable `selectedFile` will contain the path you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know how can I add the FolderBrowserDialog, instead of OpenFileDialog? Ineed to ask for directory not selecting a file. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use the `FolderBrowserDialog` from `System.Windows.Forms`. This is the basic windows dialog. You may use some third party libraries for a better one